# Why doesn't the telescopic series $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n(n+1)}$ diverge? It is a sum of harmonic series!

Tags: sequences-and-series

Since both harmonic series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1n$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{-1}{n+1}$ diverge and

$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n(n+1)}
=\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac1n + \frac{-1}{n+1}\right),
$$

why doesn't the telescopic series diverge?

Comment: $\sum 1$ and $\sum -1$ diverge, so their "sum" should also ...

Comment: Because $+\infty$ plus $-\infty$ can be anything.

Comment: These type of arguments is exactly why they call it *series* and not infinite sum

Comment: Because you can only rearrange absolutely convergent series with confidence

Comment: I know the telescopic series converges, and I understand why for various reasons. The point of the question, which is missed by several answers, is about how the sum of two divergent series can converge.

Comment: There is no theorem which says that the sum of two divergent series is divergent.  Indeed this is not always true, as shown by some of the examples given.  My suggestion: go through the proof that the sum of two convergent series is convergent; try to adapt it to show that the sum of two divergent series is divergent; see if you can spot the steps where this attempted proof fails to work.

Comment: *It is a sum of harmonic series!* - Wrong! It is an *alternating* sum of harmonic series! :-) And the reason for its convergence is precisely due to the fact that the two divergent tendencies ultimately cancel each other out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sums of divergent series are not neccesarily divergent. For example $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1} -1$ are both divergent. However their sum $\sum_{n \geq 1}1+(-1)$ is constant 0 and hence convergent.

Another way to prove convergence is to use the majorand $\frac{1}{n^2}$:

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \underbrace{\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2 + n} \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2}}_{\text{Every element is smaller}} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 3):

Because infinitely many terms cancel
$$S_n=(1+\frac{-1}{2})+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{-1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{-1}{4})+...+(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{-1}{n+1})=1+\frac{-1}{n+1}$$ Now you can complete

Answer (score 2):

Let us check the partial sum. We claim that $\sum_{n=1}^N 1/n-1/(n+1)=1-1/(N+1)$

We proceed to prove it by induction on $N$. If $N=0$, so $\sum_{n=1}^0 1/n-1/(n+1)=0$ and $1-1(N+1)=0$. Suppose we have proven the assertion for $N$. Then

\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} 1/n-1/(n+1)=1/(N+1)-1/(N+2)+\sum_{n=1}^N 1/n-1/(n+1)\\
=1/(N+1)-1/(N+2)+1-1/(N+1)\\
=1-1/(N+2)\end{align}

So we have that $S_N=1-1/(N+1)$ for all $N$.

Taking the limit $\lim_{N\to \infty}S_N=\lim_{N\to \infty}1-1/(N+1)=1 $

More general:

**Proposition**: Suppose $a_n \to 0$. Then $\sum_n a_n-a_{n+1}$ converges.

Proof: We first claim that $s_N=\sum _{n=0}^N a_n- a_{n+1}=a_0-a_{N+1}$. The claim is trivially true when $N=0$, since $a_0-a_1=a_0= a_{N+1}$. Now suppose we have already proven our assertion for $N\ge 0$, then 
\begin{align}\sum _{n=0}^{N+1} a_n- a_{n+1}=(a_{N+1}-a_{N+2})+\sum _{n=0}^{N} a_n- a_{n+1}\\
= (a_{N+1}-a_{N+2}) +(a_0-a_{N+1})\\
=a_0-a_{N+2}\end{align}

Closing the induction. Since $S_n=a_0-a_{n+1}$ and $a_n \to 0$. Then $S_n\to a_0$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that by definition, the series $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges precisely if the **sequence** $(s_n)$ converges, where $s_n$ is the partial sum 
$$s_n=\sum_1^n a_k.$$
By looking at our particular series, in "partial fraction" form, we can see that because of the cancellations, we have
$$s_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$
It is clear that the sequence $(s_n)$ converges to $1$.